# Titanium ti.storekit returns empty products

Tags: ios, titanium, app-store-connect, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am using ti.storekit to do in app billing. Everything seems to work, but when I run the following code:

```
Storekit.requestProducts(["FooPro"], function (evt)
{
  Ti.API.info('evt:' + JSON.stringify(evt, undefined, 2));
  //hideLoading();
  if (!evt.success)
  {
    alert('ERROR: We failed to talk to Apple!');
  }
  else if (evt.invalid)
  {
    alert('ERROR: We requested an invalid product!');
  }
  else
  {
    item = evt.products;
    Ti.API.info('gotProducts:' + JSON.stringify(item, undefined, 2));
    success(item[0]);
  }
});
```

I get a successful response, but with no products:

```
evt:{
  "type": "callback",
  "products": [
    {}
  ],
  "source": {},
  "success": true
}
```

So there is no products, and just silently fails. In iTunes connect, in the product, i have an in app product with the product id of `FooPro` (although it is pending review). I am not sure what else I am doing wrong. everything *seems* to work, i just get back an empty products array and I cant figure out why.

This is also causing the error so that when I call

```
// product = {} since the above returned it as empty
Storekit.purchase(product);
```

it errors and tells me this as well:

```
Passing individual args to `purchase` is DEPRECATED. Call `purchase` passing in a dictionary of arguments.
addTransactionObserver` should be called before `purchase`
```

EDIT: the products, when using Ti.API.info() to output the contents show as empty. Yet after signing into itunes with the test account on the device, the products still do show up as empty, but when I do more debugging, the product object seems to actually be:

```
{'My product description'}
```

So when I call

```
Storekit.purchase(product)
```

It seems like it's really calling

```
Storekit.purchase({'My product description'})
```

So it appears to be failing here because the purchase call never triggers the `transactionState` event listener.

Environment:
 - **iPhone**: 5, 4s

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your app status "Waiting for Upload?" Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: Yes I am testing on an iPhone 5. I have read a lot that it tends not to work on a simulator. However, yes; the app status is still waiting for upload. I will try submitting it and see if that helps.

Comment: Currently everything is waiting for review. And I net the same results.

Comment: You have to test on a real device, I'm wondering if the deprecated message is causing problems. The Ti.Storekit module may have to be updated...

Comment: Yes as I mentioned, I am testing on an iPhone 5. Well, to me at least, it appears as if I am getting that deprecated message, because the only item passed to it (product) is an empty object.

Comment: Well, it seems that the test user also had to be signed into app store. Now when I click the purchase button, it get the sandbox popup to buy the product. But the products still (using Ti.API.info()) show as empty, although the product also at other times simply is an object containing the product description, rather than the product id.

Comment: I also still get this error ```Passing individual args to `purchase` is DEPRECATED. Call `purchase` passing in a dictionary of arguments.``` and ```addTransactionObserver` should be called before `purchase` ```.

the object it seems to get, is simply an object with a string of the product description. so the ```transactionState``` never seems to get triggered to finalize the transaction.

Comment: @skift - did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Nope. It never worked. I found more people with newer apps that storekit did not work for them. It seems that it was just poorly made. There was another plugin available that seemed better. But it costs. We eventually just scrapped the idea for in app purchasing for that app. since we eventually want to go native anyways and move away from titanium. too many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Whow... I've been playing around with it further, and there is something weired going on...

Even when you get `[{}]` for products, `products[0].title` brings back the actual product title.
It's as though it's there, but hiding from the trace statement.

All you then needed to do is send {product:e.products[0]} to purchase, and voila :

```
Storekit.requestProducts(productIDs, function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("GOT PRODUCTS : "+JSON.stringify(e));
        // 'GOT PRODUCTS : {"type":"callback","products":[{}],"source":{},"success":true}'

    Ti.API.info('PROD TITLE : '+e.products[0].title);
        // 'PROD TITLE : My IAP product'

    Storekit.purchase({product:e.products[0]});
    // You need to implement 'transactionState' and addTransactionObserver to carry on from here - see the example code in the module package for that
});
```

And make sure you set `Storekit.autoFinishTransactions = false;` - or you won't get the final purchase event after the user has bought your product.

Comment: Thats great to hear! But since I am not using this, I cannot easily test it. if someone else can confirm this works for them, i will mark it as the answer for now.